# BMS extra balance leads

Tags: lithium-ion, bms

I am repairing a battery pack that had 14 pouch cells. The original BMS had 13 leads. Black on negative with the center cell in the pack not connected.

I removed two bad cells. Both on the negative end. I am replacing the BMS with again 13 leads. So I have one extra red.

If I terminate (isolate) it, should I use the first, (the one by the negative) or the last positive?

These pouch cells have a full charge of 4.2. I have adjusted the charger to 50.4.

I am using this BMS because 10 cell BMS are considered 36 V and I feel this is to far from my working voltage.

I am doing this for free for an old man. He has a 1000 W front drive tricycle. This battery is 50 Ah. So when working correctly it gave him great range. I replaced the motor controller and loaned him a 48 V 13 Ah but the range is just insufficient for his needs.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> 14 pouch cells ... BMS had 13 leads

That's wrong. 14 cells in series require a 14-cell BMS. The balance connector for that BMS will 15 circuits. (Rarely, it may have only 14 wires by using one of the main terminals as the 15th circuit.) A BMS with 13 leads is for 12 cells in series. You can't use it to protect a 14S battery.

Comment: I agree with you. But that is how I found the original build. The replacement bms I have has one extra positive lead. Because of removing the two cells. Can I isolate the extra lead or will this just fault the bms? Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: "Can I isolate the extra lead" No. I repeat: for a 14S battery you need a 14S BMS. No other way.